# Real inventory vs Finance inventory

Tags: maximo

I'm pretty new to Maximo and I have a question about how things should be handled.  We have a project of integrating our ERP with Maximo using MIF interfaces.  I'd like to know how you performed this in your company as I'm sure we're not the only one facing this challenges.

Let's go pretty simple about the Inventory.  Receiving will be performed in our ERP and sent to Maximo.  "Consumption" and inventory movements will be performed in Maximo and interfaced back to our ERP.  so far so good, standard process.

However, there's a difference in the real inventory vs the inventory from a Financial perspective.  As an example, we have let's say 3 cutters (same part number, different serial number).  We have 2 in the internal storage and 1 in the machine where its being used.  Once it is in the machine, it's known as "consumed" by finance.  So from a finance point of view, there's only 2 in stock.  From the tooling guy however, there's 3!  The one in the machine can be taken out and replaced by one of the two others.

How are things like that handled in maximo?  Any help, advices would be appreciated.

Regards
M.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you plan to track on the individual level (track cutters by individual asset tags or serial numbers) or on the group level (3 cutters with the same item number)

If the cutter is treated as inventory and not as an asset, once it is issued then it is considered used. You can opt to use "Condition Code" and give each item a value from 0 to 100. Think of this value as depreciation. If a cutter is swapped out, then the new cutter (100%) is issued, and the replaced cutter is disposed of or returned to the shelf with a diminished value (e.g. 25%).